# Igraph Identifying nodes based on centrality scores

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

I'm running the `igraph` package for some network analysis on this example dataset

```
structure(list(ï..Column1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), Column2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Column3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), Column4 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Column5 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Eric ", 
"Jim", "Matt", "Tim"), class = "factor"), Column6 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Column7 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Eric", 
"Erica", "Mary "), class = "factor"), Column8 = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Beth", "Loranda", "Matt"), class = "factor"), 
    Column9 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Courtney ", 
    "Heather ", "Patrick"), class = "factor"), Column10 = structure(4:1, .Label = c("Beth", 
    "Heather", "John", "Loranda "), class = "factor"), Column11 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), Column12 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), Column13 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), Column14 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), Column15 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

Here is the edgelist for anyone who wants to skip the step of finding that

```
structure(c("Jim", "Eric ", "Tim", "Matt", "Jim", "Eric ", "Tim", 
"Matt", "Jim", "Eric ", "Tim", "Matt", "Jim", "Eric ", "Tim", 
"Matt", "Eric", "Mary ", "Erica", "Mary ", "Matt", "Loranda", 
"Beth", "Matt", "Heather ", "Patrick", "Courtney ", "Patrick", 
"Loranda ", "John", "Heather", "Beth"), .Dim = c(16L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Column5", "value")))
```

I'm trying to calculate centrality for each of the nodes in the network using this code (mat is my edgelist matrix)

```
g1=graph_from_edgelist(mat)
degree.cent <- centr_degree(g1, mode = "all")
degree.cent
```

My output is something like this

```
> degree.cent
$`res`
 [1] 4 1 4 2 4 1 6 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1

$centralization
[1] 0.1479592

$theoretical_max
[1] 392
```

I know 'degree$res` is my centrality score measures, but what isn't clear to me is which nodes are actually receiving that score. I looked up a tutorial [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/centrality-network-analysis-R#types), but all it says is the first score is "node 1". There's no indication of what node 1 is or an easy way to identify that

Comment: Do you want `degree(g1, mode = "all")`?

Comment: Yep that works too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are getting incorrect results as some of the names contain spaces (Eric, Marry, Heather, ...). So, let

```
mat <- gsub(" ", "", mat)
g1 <- graph_from_edgelist(mat)
degree.cent <- centr_degree(g1, mode = "all")
```

Now we may extract the corresponding names of vertices and combine them with your result:

```
setNames(degree.cent$res, V(g1)$name)
#      Jim     Eric     Mary      Tim    Erica     Matt  Loranda     Beth  Heather 
#        4        5        2        4        1        6        2        2        2 
#  Patrick Courtney     John 
#        2        1        1
```

Comment: Awesome! Would you know an easy function to include these count data back into a wide format dataframe based on the name of the people? Like "if name is "Jim" in row add a new cell in new column containing degree centrality score? I know i could use a for loop statement, but I'm trying to be computationally conservative

Comment: Also why do the spaces create issues in the function?

Comment: @M76, I presume there already is a column `Name` or so. In that case you may want something like `merge(df, cbind(Centrality = degree.cent$res, Name = V(g1)$name))`. Also you may take a look at `?join` from `dplyr`. Spaces alone don't create issues (although it's easy for them to appear in any step then). The problem was that there were names of both types - with spaces and without, like "Eric " and "Eric". Because of that there were too many entities in the graph. So, the actual issue was inconsistency in names.

Comment: Great! that explains everything